# igraph plot conditional vertex color

Tags: r, colors, conditional-statements, igraph, vertex

I'm new to R and iGraph. I'm trying to make a vertex in column position #1, appear in a specific color.

My data comes in from CSV and looks like this:

```
CL1920  202.80  V66.7   198.89  511.9   799.02  401.9   696.1   388.01  202.80                                                                                                                               
RM119041 331.82 294.10                                                                                                                                                                                       
RM38755 331.82  294.10  276.0   331.0   294.10                                                                                                                   
HK54701 331.82  294.10  276.0   331.0   294.10  401.9   V10.51
....
```

My plot script look looks something like this:

```
dat <- read.csv("data.csv", header =F)
g <- graph.data.frame(dat, directed = F)
colCount <- 1+ count.fields("dat.csv", sep = ",")
V(g)$label <- NA
set.seed(10)
par <- par()$mar; par(mar=rep(0, 4))
plot (g, layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold,
      vertex.frame.color = "#FFFFFF",
      vertex.size = 5,
      edge.width = 2.5+ (log(colCount)/max(log(colCount))),
      edge.color = "Grey60")
```

I've tried unsuccessfully to set vertex.color. Examples like this seem to default to "lightblue"

```
 V(g)$color <- ifelse (V(g)$V1, "red", "blue")
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The example data looks messed up. Is it a table at all?

Comment: What do you mean by "unsuccessfully"? What is `V(g)$V1`? `vertex.color` behaves exactly like `vertex.frame.color`, so if you can set one of them, you can probably set the other one as well.

Comment: I think the data is valid. It's a "list of sets" with first element in the row being a unique object ID and the following row items are 0-n members. V(g)$V1 is an attempt to address 'column #1' of the row (the object ID)... I suspect I have this syntax horribly wrong hence my `ifelse` statement gets ignored. I want the ObjectID vertex to be a different color from the members.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "valid". `graph.data.frame()` is typically used on tables, where the first two columns define the edges. So your first edge is from 'CL1920' to '202.80'? You don't have a `V1` attribute in your example either, and you are referring to it in your code. Again, your example (code, data or both) is messed up.

Comment: The sample data in the post is representative of the data set. Yes, the first edge is CL1920 to 202.80. The second edge would be CL1920 to V66.7 and so on. I want to set vertex.color="red" if CL1920 or RM119041 or RM38755 etc.. I'm unclear how to assign one vertex.color for g[[,1]] and another for g[[,2:]]

Comment: I see. Then please modify your question, asking how to set the color of vertices that appear in the first column. What is `V(g)$V1`? You are either not showing all your code, or the `V1` attribute is never set, so `V(g)$V1` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So it seems (from the comments) that the goal is to set the vertex color based on whether the vertex appears in the first column of the `dat` data frame. Here is a way:

```
V(g)$color <- ifelse(V(g)$name %in% dat[,1], "red", "blue")
plot(g)
```

Comment: That did it, thank you. It seems so obvious now... Thanks for being so patient!